# Block site from being on Safari Top Sites

Tags: safari

I have the following issue: some sites I use quite often, as facebook, appears at the top sites with several different urls, depending on the person I chat and so on. I remove them manually, which is quite boring. I would like to know if there is any way to block facebook and other sites from being add to Safari's Top Sites. Someone knows how to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[From Apple's support page:](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH11928?viewlocale=en_US) On the Top Sites page, click the Edit button. Then do any of the following:

- To specify that a page be kept in Top Sites and not replaced by other pages visited more often, click the pin icon in the page’s upper-left corner.
- To reverse this action, click the pin icon again.
- **To specify that a page never be included in Top Sites, click the X in the page’s upper-left corner.**
- To display 24, 12, or 6 webpage previews, click Small, Medium, or Large.
- To rearrange the pages, drag them.

When you finish making changes, click Done.

Comment: Well, that's what I wanted to say when I said that I remove the pages manually: by clicking X when the duplicates appear. I wanted a way to force Top Sites to skip adding duplicates sites from the same domain from appearing at the Top Sites.

Answer (score 2):

If you know which sites that you want on your Top Sites, you could **fill the grid with pinned sites**. This way, more sites would not be added since they would not be able to replace pinned sites.

[image: Pin Site]

Comment: This would solve the issue, but I wouldn't like to have to pin all sites at the top sites, so it can dynamically add sites as I change the sites I usually use.