# How can exclude a whole site from Safari Top sites (and not just an URL)?

Tags: safari

[In this other question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/97499/block-site-from-being-on-safari-top-sites), I've asked how to remove a domain from being added to the Safari Top Sites.

Unfortunately it seems that the answer may not be that easy as I though. I've just discovered that the list with the banned domains is on the path `~/Library/Safari/TopSites.plist`, and I tried to add a domain with a wildcard to the BannedURLStrings, i.e. `https://apple.stackexchange.com/*`, but it doesn't work. Safari removes it as it seems to be invalid. Someone knows if it is possible to add a wildcard, or if they have another syntax, i.e `https://apple.stackexchange.com/%`.